# Look forward to meeting you both vs. Look forward to meeting you

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-number

I'm confused about the need to add the word *both* when  using *you* as a plural that refers to more than one individual.

T/e first *you* sentence also refers to two people:

> We look forward to meeting you this evening as well as getting to know **you both** over the coming year.

Comment: I wouldn't have known there were two people if you hadn't put "both".  Maybe it would be different in context.

Comment: There's a ***need*** to use "both" only if it is otherwise unclear. If it's not unclear, go with whatever seems natural.

Comment: In older English, we had the luxury of "thee" vs "you".

Answer (score 1):

*Both* emphasises the speaker's interest in the two people.

Comment: So the sentence is correct "as is", and the use of "both" in the later part of the sentence places greater emphasis on the "getting to know" portion?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to say that it's grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking to both people, and they know "you" means both of them; but you can only look at one person at a time, so use "both" to ensure.